# How to get shape name from visio using C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, shapes, visio

I need to get all the shape name from the visio document.(ie) If i have two task shape in visio it automatically rename as

> task.1  and task.2   in visio

But i need to get the name **"TASK"**.
Is it possible to get that name..

**I can get the unique name of a shape** by using

```
foreach (visio.Shape shp in shape.Shapes)
        { shp.NameU // i can get task.1 and task.2 }
```

But i need to get the name **"TASK"**

Comment: Is the format always like this (task)(dot)(number) ?

Comment: @Chris  yes..!! But we cannot split from (.) because some shape name may contain (.) seems...!:(

Comment: What is the reason for down grades...??

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use "master" name and not shape name if you want to figure out the shape "type". That is, try Shape.Master.Name

Shape name (and nameU) is built by Visio automatically from it's master name and it's number of instances.

Comment: But when i try this Shape.Master.Name also am getting the same task.19 only

Comment: Ah. then your master is named like that already probably. (Task.19). You can check out the list of masters in the document (Document -> Drawing Explorer)

If you just want a marker for your shape, you can just add that as a specific shape-sheet cell for example, so you don't need to rely on names.

Comment: Si it's not possible to get that shape name right.?

Comment: can you please tellme why in my masters am having both name Task ans Task.13

Comment: It depends on what you mean on "shape name". I.e. in principle you can assign any name to a shape, visio just provides a reasonable default. Name does not identify shape type.

About masters "Task" and "Task.13" - when you edit a master and draw a new shape to the drawing, Visio adds new master copy to the document stencil.

Comment: Does it have a chance to add a new master copy to stencil automatically...?

Comment: Hmm didn't quite get what you mean; Visio documents are self-sufficient, i.e. they contain everything they need and do not depend on each other. For example, a drawing document contains all masters it needs, so it is actually independent from stencils.
Every time you drop a shape to a document, it's master is also copied to the document (uless it exists there already).

Comment: my problem is in my Visio document I didn't edit the master name . Even Though name of master get renamed .

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your own name. The [NameU](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765535(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Shape class pecifies the universal name of a Shape object. You can change it programmatically.

Also you may find the following properties of the Shape class helpful:

- [ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767467(v=office.15).aspx) - gets the ID of an object.
- [NameID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767852(v=office.15).aspx) - returns a unique name for a shape.